# can I resize UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want something like an image and table as the image will finish and data on table, so is it possible, as designed below

+++++
IMAGE
+++++

### ---------

### ---------

### ---------

---

------- > showing table cells, so first there should be image then a resized UITableView?

Comment: yes this is possible with the standard methods tableView.frame = CGRectMake(....);

Comment: your question's title and text dont match.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, if you resize the UITable then there can be a UIImage simply in ViewDidLoad, like we do for UIPickerView, now can u understand my question?

Comment: @fluchtpunkht, how is it possible, can U make a table for me and resize it as u r saying by using CGRectMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand your question... but as far as I understand you can set an imageView in the header of the tableView to hold your image

**EDIT**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
CGRect frame;


frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    imageView.image = someImage;
imageView.opaque = YES;


return imageView;
}
```

Just add something like this in your View Controller.

Comment: Bhai, you got it right, but should I make a new file which inherit the UITableViewController, or I should make a UITable?

Comment: but I have an other class which is subclass of UITableViewController, now the controller, so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

your can also use,

```
    [tableView setTableHeaderView:yourImageView];
```

This will show the Image on the header of the table view.
Use this code, where you are allocating / creating tableview

Comment: I am inheriting UITableViewController, now making new tableView separtely, now ?

Comment: no, that is not required. You can use `self.tableView` for accessing the tableview from UITableViewController

Comment: for suppose I have an file, Status.m and Status.h, now it is already inheriting the UITableViewController, so where should I put your code so that I can use image?

Comment: where should I put your code, viewDidLoad, or any where else?

Comment: I did it, but this is not what I want, because when you scroll up, then image will go upside, I want image all time there ....

Comment: Ahhhh..then this is not going to work.  I believe UITableViewController requires that its view be a UITableView.

You can change  UITableViewController to subclassing UIViewController and implementing the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols. Then you can have your view be whatever you want, including shifting your UITableView down and adding a UIImageView. Alternatively, you can add subview on UIWindow, that  will can be displayed on the top of UITableViewController

Comment: This is the code, if you want to add subview on the window, so it will be displayed on the top. `UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 40)];
      [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
 
      UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
     [window addSubview:view];
Use this code in viewWillAppear, but you will have to remove this view from window, when you move from this view to another view, so it will not be displayed on other controllers

Comment: This will make the image scroll with the table. If you want it fixed to the top you need to add it outside of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass a UIViewController, and implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols. And then in the viewDidLoad method create a UITableView and add it to self.view. You'll also need to create a retain property called tableView and set it to the Tableview you created in viewDidLoad.

When you create the tableView you can set it's frame to anything you want, but remember to set it's autoresizing mask appositely (normally o flexible width and flexible height)

Then you can add your imageView to above the tableview